# What's with "The following line works around an ASP.NET compiler warning" in MVC Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I did a quick search on SO for this and didn't come up with anything.

Doesn't

```
<%-- The following line works around an ASP.NET compiler warning --%>
<%: ""%>
```

seem like a bit of a hack?
what's the point of this, and is the MS Dev Team doing anything to work towards a resolve?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but that line only appears in VB.NET-based projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a writeup in the ASP.NET forums about this.  Without that line, you might get compiler warnings that look something like "__o is not declared".  This work around prevents those from ever appearing.

From the asp.net forums...

[ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/923745/1266105.aspx)

> We have finally obtained reliable
>   repro and identified the underlying
>   issue. A trivial repro looks like
>   this:
>
> ```
>  <% if (true) { %>
> <%=1%>
> <% } %>
> <%=2%>
> ```
>
> In order to provide intellisense in <%= %> blocks at
>   design time, ASP.NET generates
>   assignment to a temporary __o variable
>   and language (VB or C#) then provide
>   the intellisense for the variable.
>   That is done when page compiler sees
>   the first <%= ... %> block.  But here,
>   the block is inside the if, so after
>   the if closes, the variable goes out
>   of scope.  We end up generating
>   something like this:
>
> ```
>    if (true) { 
>         object @__o;
>         @__o = 1;
>    }
>    @__o = 2;
> ```
>
> The workaround is to add a dummy
>   expression early in the page.  E.g.
>   <%="" %>.  This will not render
>   anything, and it will make sure that
>   __o is declared top level in the Render method, before any potential
>   ‘if’ (or other scoping) statement.

Comment: thanks, that answers the first question. Any thoughts on whether or not they'll actually fix it to work properly?

Comment: Not sure, I don't know the Visual Studio engine well enough to even pose a suggestion to get around scoping issues :/

Comment: Of course this error has been known since at least VS 2005, so it doesn't look like there is a quick fix on the VS side of things.